# python - generalizing y-axis limits for mean line in density plots

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have this simple dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": np.random.randint(50,53,size=100),
             "Y": np.random.randint(200,300,size=100),
             "Z": np.random.randint(400,800,size=100)})
```

And as I have many columns (all of them numeric), I did this loop in order to do a specific plot:

```
for i in df.columns:
    data = df[i]
    data.plot(kind="kde")
    plt.vlines(x=data.mean(),ymin=0, ymax=0.01, linestyles="dotted")
    plt.show()
```

However, I'm having trouble trying to generalize the `ymax` argument of `plt.vlines()`, as I need to get the maximum y-axis value of each density plot in order to plot the mean vline of each plot accordingly. I have tried with `np.argmax()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.plot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) returns [`matplotlib.axes.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) object. You can use [`get_ylim()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_ylim) function to get ymin and ymax.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"X": np.random.randint(50,53,size=100),
             "Y": np.random.randint(200,300,size=100),
             "Z": np.random.randint(400,800,size=100)})

for i in df.columns:
    data = df[i]
    ax = data.plot(kind="kde")
    ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim()
    plt.vlines(x=data.mean(),ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, linestyles="dotted")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: @ALollz Thank you for your review. I think it really depends on what the OP wants to draw. In his quesiton, he says he needs to *get the maximum y-axis value of each density plot*. I offer a solution for him. He didn't claim whether he needs the verticel line from bottom to top.

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of the kde corresponding to the mean, you could extract the curve from the plot and interpolate it at the position of the mean:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"X": 20 + np.random.randint(-1, 2, size=100).cumsum(),
                   "Y": 30 + np.random.randint(-1, 2, size=100).cumsum(),
                   "Z": 40 + np.random.randint(-1, 2, size=100).cumsum()})
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for col in df.columns:
    data = df[col]
    data.plot(kind="kde", ax=ax)
    x = data.mean()
    kdeline = ax.lines[-1]
    ymax = np.interp(x, kdeline.get_xdata(), kdeline.get_ydata())
    ax.vlines(x=data.mean(), ymin=0, ymax=ymax, linestyles="dotted")
ax.set_ylim(ymin=0) # ax.vlines() moves the bottom ylim; set it back to 0
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Answer (score 1):

Use [`plt.axvline`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.axvline.html). You specify the limits as numbers in the range [0,1], 0 being the bottom of the plot, 1 being the top.

```
for i in df.columns:
    data = df[i]
    data.plot(kind="kde")
    plt.axvline(data.mean(), 0, 1, linestyle='dotted', color='black')
    plt.show()
```

[image]