# python - generalizing y-axis limits for mean line in GROUPED density plots

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": np.random.randint(50,53,size=100),
             "Y": np.random.randint(200,300,size=100),
             "Z": np.random.randint(400,800,size=100),
             "Cat": np.random.choice(["Buy","Don't buy"], size=100)})
```

And as I have many columns (all of them numeric except one), I did this loop in order to do a specific plot:

```
for i in ["X", "Y", "Z"]:
    data = df.groupby("Cat")
    ax = data[i].plot(kind="kde")
    #ymin, ymax = ax.get_ylim() # Here is the error
    plt.vlines(x=data.mean()[data.mean().index == "Buy"][i],ymin=0, ymax=0.5, linestyles="dotted")
    plt.vlines(x=data.mean()[data.mean().index == "Don't buy"][i],ymin=0, ymax=0.5, linestyles="dotted")
    plt.show()
```

I need to get the maximum y-axis value of each density plot and categorical group, in order to plot the mean vlines of each plot and each categorical group. I have trying to find a workaround on the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63472360/python-generalizing-y-axis-limits-for-mean-line-in-density-plots). But it gives me the error `'Series' object has no attribute 'get_ylim'`.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

Specifically, the ymax should be the same for each density curve as there will be two density curves per plot. If their colors are different (the same as the color of the density curves for example) would be amazing, but not strictly necessary. The ymax can be different among plots.

Comment: `ax = data[i].plot(kind="kde")` - what is `ax` after this line executes? `data = df.groupby("Cat")` should not be **in** the for loop.

Comment: What exactly do you want to output to look like? How far up should the line go? (full height of plot? up to the curve? whatever?). Should it be colored like each of the curves? It was ambiguous in the other question and you got three very different answers, with a mix of up/down votes.

Comment: @ALollz In the other question it didn't matter as it was just one density curve per plot. In this one, the ymax should be the same for each plot as there will be two density curves per plot. If their colors are different (the same as the color of the density curves for example) would be amazing, but not strictly necessary. I edited the question for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to get the maximum y-axis value of each density plot and categorical group

```
for i in ["X", "Y", "Z"]:
    data = df.groupby("Cat")
    ax = data[i].plot(kind="kde")
    ...
```

`ax` is a Pandas Series with an Axes for 'Buy' and 'Don't buy'.

```
> ax
Cat
Buy          AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
Don't buy    AxesSubplot(0.125,0.11;0.775x0.77)
Name: X, dtype: object
```

You can get the max y limit with

```
> max(ax['Buy'].get_ylim())
0.5447082895597888
> max(ax["Don't buy"].get_ylim())
0.5447082895597888
```

Or get the limits with.

```
> import matplotlib as mpl
> ax.apply(mpl.axes.Axes.get_ylim)
Cat
Buy          (-0.026485399247623134, 0.556196332564079)
Don't buy    (-0.026485399247623134, 0.556196332564079)
Name: Z, dtype: object
>
```